# Downloading from arXiv and running the source on overleaf?

Tags: biblatex, overleaf, arxiv, bbl

I downloaded the source of a paper from arXiv, and extracted the files, using 7-zip. I've ended up with a tex file, and a bbl file. I then uploaded them to overleaf.

When I click recompile, the paper is created almost perfectly. The bibliography, however doesn't work. I get the error "cannot find bibliography.bib".

My question is: can I get the bibliography to work somehow?

I've already searched for answers, but the majority of questions are about the opposite problem- going from an overleaf project to submitting to arXiv. I want to go the other way: download source from arXiv, and run it on overleaf.

Comment: Can you link to the specific paper on arxiv so we can check if the bib file is available?

Comment: a bbl file is not a bib file it is the output generated from bib by bibtex. You can use that directly via \input  instead of using `\bibliography` or there may be a bib file in the arxiv source zip

Comment: https://arxiv.org/format/2310.09182  I put \input{the bbl file} but that failed to recompile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The file uses biblatex, and the author has not provided the bib file.

Fortunately ctan has a package that addresses exactly this.

Add `biblatex-readbbl` after `biblatex` eg after the `%LT-SKIP-END` comment in this example

```
%%% LT-SKIP-END
\usepackage[bblfile=\jobname]{biblatex-readbbl}
```

The document then processes without error, using the pre-made `bbl` file.

[image]

---

You may find (including in comments under this question) suggestions to replace `\bibliography{..}` by `\input{\jobname.bib}` but that only applies to classic **bibtex** use, not **biblatex**.

---

As noted in comments:

- On Overleaf you may need to replace `\jobname`  by the name of the `.bbl` file (without the `.bbl` extension), so in the OP's real example `[bblfile=DC-LPPL-LI]`.
- Also, if the document is old (at whatever point you are reading this) the `.bbl` file may not be compatible with the version of biblatex in the current texlive, however you can use the overleaf menu to process your project with a texlive of a suitable date. (At the time of writing Overleaf offer texlive versions from 2014 to 2023).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I pasted the line "\usepackage[bblfile=\jobname]{biblatex-readbbl}
" in the line below %%% LT-SKIP-END, in the main latex file.  That didn't work. Did I misunderstand your answer?

Comment: @SeanThrasher ah overleaf messes with jobname sorry use `[bblfile=DC-LPPL-LI]` on overleaf (I tested on a local installation)

Comment: This will only work as long as the `biblatex` versions used to generate the `.bbl` file and the `biblatex` version you use to compile the document later are not too different (more precisely if the share the `.bbl` file version). Sometimes new developments in `biblatex` require changes to the `.bbl` structure. So a more sustainable long-term solution would be to try and obtain actual `.bib` data for the relevant entries.

Comment: @moewe hmm  yes thanks for adding this warning, although I'm not sure saying it's impossible to use the arxiv source and you need to contact the author is quite the answer the op wanted. for some documents it's probably easier to locate an older copy of biblatex (as overleaf has all texlive 2014 - 2023)

Comment: @moewe I added a note to the answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your answer but I'm trying to learn how to do this generally, if that's possible. I've tried doing the same trick for arguments, but it doesn't seem to work. For instance, for the article  https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.03333 can I use \usepackage[bblfile=\jobname]{biblatex-readbbl}
, and where do I put that? Thanks

Comment: as noted above on overleaf you can't use `\jobname` use `[bblfile=aaaa]`  where `aaaa.bib` is the name of the bib file in the download from arxiv  but that file is not using biblatex, so simply replace `\bibliography{tomography}` by `\input{main.bbl}` @SeanThrasher there is no "general" fix, you are basically fixing errors in the tex source provided by authors that do not run as provided.